# ¿How can I create a pagination of records? (JSF)

Tags: jsf, pagination

I'm doing a hotel room reservation page with Java Server Faces. I have a base template that contains a hotel search, with an index template that is where I show the results. I'm loading all the hotels on the front page, like cover. And I show only 9 hotels so that they do not overflow the hotels of the DIV:

[image]

Ok, I have only 10 hotels registered in the database in total .... I want to make a pagination for my page where I display only 9 hotels per page .... the result of having this, as I have 10 hotels in the database, it would be that on the next page I should only see 1 single hotel.

This is my index page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{buscador.cargarPortada()}"/>
</f:metadata>
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./templates/base.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="form2">
                <h:dataTable value="#{buscador.display}" var="res">
                 <h:column>
                     <h:outputLabel value="#{res.a}" escape="false"/>
                 </h:column>                    
                 <h:column>
                      <h:outputLabel value="#{res.b}" escape="false"/> 
                 </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                     <h:outputLabel value="#{res.c}" escape="false"/>
                 </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

I am using a dataTable to display the results. I have two classes: a class that handles rows of the dataTable, and another class that constructs the display boxes of each hotel

With this class I construct each box in the table:

```
    package Clases;

public class ResultElement {
     private String nombre, imagen, localidad;
     private String display;
    public ResultElement(String nombre, String imagen, String localidad){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.imagen=imagen;
        this.localidad=localidad;
        display = "<div id='HotP'><b><p style=\"text-align:center;font-
    style:italic;color:red\">" + nombre + "</p></b>"
               +"<img src=\"resources/images/" + imagen + 
    "\"style=\"width:160px;height:70px;border:1px solid gray;\"/><br>"
                + "<span style=\"color: darkblue;text-align: center;\">"+ 
    localidad +"</span></div>";
    }
    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the imagen
     */
    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    /**
     * @param imagen the imagen to set
     */
    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    /**
     * @return the localidad
     */
    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    /**
     * @param localidad the localidad to set
     */
    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    /**
     * @return the display
     */
    public String getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    /**
     * @param display the display to set
     */
    public void setDisplay(String display) {
        this.display = display;
    }
}
```

With this class I manage the rows of the table. I show 3 results per row:

```
package Clases;

public class DisplayResult {
private String A, B, C;

public DisplayResult(String a, String b, String c){
    A = a;
    B = b;
    C = c;
}
/**
 * @return the A
 */
public String getA() {
    return A;
}

/**
 * @param A the A to set
 */
public void setA(String A) {
    this.A = A;
}

/**
 * @return the B
 */
public String getB() {
    return B;
}

/**
 * @param B the B to set
 */
public void setB(String B) {
    this.B = B;
}

/**
 * @return the C
 */
public String getC() {
    return C;
}

/**
 * @param C the C to set
 */
public void setC(String C) {
    this.C = C;
}

}
```

This class is where I will load the cover of the page and perform searches:

```
    package Beans;

import Clases.DisplayResult;
import Clases.ResultElement;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import Database.GestorDB;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author SEMINARIO
 */
@Named(value = "portada")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Buscador {
     private String fechaE, fechaS, localidad;
    private int personas;
    private static ArrayList<DisplayResult> displayList;
    private ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<>();   
    public Buscador() {
       displayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getFechaE() {
        return fechaE;
    }

    public void setFechaE(String fechaE) {
        this.fechaE = fechaE;
    }

    public String getFechaS() {
        return fechaS;
    }

    public void setFechaS(String fechaS) {
        this.fechaS = fechaS;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public int getPersonas() {
        return personas;
    }

    public void setPersonas(int personas) {
        this.personas = personas;
    }

    public ArrayList<DisplayResult> getDisplay() {
        return displayList;
    }

    public void setDisplay(ArrayList<DisplayResult> listaResultado) {
        Buscador.displayList = listaResultado;
    }

    public void agregarResultado(DisplayResult resultado){
        Buscador.displayList.add(resultado);
    }

    public void limpiarResultados(){
        Buscador.displayList.clear();
        aux.clear();
    }

    public void calibrar(){
        do{           
            if(aux.size()%3 != 0)
               aux.add("");
        }while(aux.size()%3 != 0);
    }    

    public void cargarPortada(){       
        try{
            ResultSet rs = GestorDB.getConsulta("SELECT HOTELES.NOMBRE AS A, HOTELES.IMGHOTEL, LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE AS B FROM HOTELES INNER JOIN LOCALIDADES"
                + " ON LOCALIDADES.IDLOCALIDADES = HOTELES.LOCALIDADES_IDLOCALIDADES FETCH FIRST 9 ROWS ONLY");
            while(rs.next()){
               ResultElement res = new ResultElement(rs.getString("A"), rs.getString("IMGHOTEL"),rs.getString("B"));
               aux.add(res.getDisplay());
            }  
            calibrar();
            for(int i = 0; i < aux.size(); i+=3){
                DisplayResult obj = new DisplayResult(aux.get(i),aux.get(i+1),aux.get(i+2));
                displayList.add(obj);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Buscador.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
}
```

I thought of controlling the pagination of my page with my arrayList but the truth is that I do not know how to place it in the dataTable ...

Is there an easy and practical way to do it?

Comment: I don't know if you're able to use third party libraries, but I guess [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml) is what you want?

Comment: Apart from that, some tips: don't use `@Named` and `@ManagedBean` together, either go with one or another. And the embedded HTML code in `ResultElement` class seems quite messy, I would rather do the HTML stuff in the facelet file.

Comment: And `@Named` is the more futureproof of the two. And I would make sure the JSF 'controller' has no SQL in it... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao

Comment: yea... something like that @XtremeBiker! Thanks for your tips too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native JSF does not have any support/have components for pagination.
You could go for a Component library like [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/), which has a pagination components like [DataGrid](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml) .

Comment: I wouldn't say there's no support. JSF itself is focused in rendering HTML code and pagination is a feature that simply gets out of that scope. However, it might be easily implemented by yourself.