# Dysfunctional logout button in a JSF application

Tags: session, jsf-2

I'm implementing a JSF application in which the credentials that a user provides are validated by looking at a MySQL database table and, in case that they were found, an HTTP session between the client and the server starts and a "welcome" page is returned in response to his/her request. *The "welcome" page contains a logout button, which **does nothing** (I checked the HTTP traffic to ensure it) when I click on it.*

`<h:commandButton value="Logout" type="submit" action="#{logoutBean.terminate}"/>`

The logout button is related to a managed bean that handles the logout process (i.e. *terminates the session and returns the start page*). The function that terminates the session and return the start page is the following:

```
public String terminate() {
    System.out.println("Here!"); //for debug
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = 
        (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    try {
        session.invalidate();
    } catch(IllegalStateException isEx) {
        isEx.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "index";
}
```

Even the message `Here!` doesn't get viewed in the console.

To be more specific, let me post the full code below.

**My welcome.xhtml page:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Admin's page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Welcome admin!</h2>
    <p>You are successfully logged in</p> <br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Logout" type="submit" action="#{logoutBean.terminate}"/>
</body>

</html>
```

**My LogoutBean.java file (handles the logout request):**

```
package loginbean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@ManagedBean(name="logoutBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LogoutBean {
    private String errorMsg = null;

    public LogoutBean() { }

    public String getErrorMsg() {
        return errorMsg;
    }

    public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

    public String terminate() {
        System.out.println("Here!");
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = 
            (HttpSession) fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        try {
            session.invalidate();
        } catch(IllegalStateException isEx) {
            isEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "index";
    }
}
```

**My start page (index.xhtml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <h:outputText value="#{loginBean.errorMsg}"
    rendered="#{loginBean.errorMsg != null}"
    style="color:red;"/>

    <h:form>
        User Name: <h:inputText id="userName" value="# {loginBean.userName}"/>
        <br/>
        Password: <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{loginBean.validate}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset"/>
    </h:form>
</body>

</html>
```

**and my LoginBean.java (handles the login request)**

```
package loginbean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import java.sql.*;

@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {
private String userName = null;
private String password = null;
private String errorMsg = null;

public LoginBean() {}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getErrorMsg() {
    return errorMsg;
}

public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {
    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
}

public String validate() {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useSSL=false", 
                "rootName", "aPassword");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select name, password from admins;");

        // Look for the credentials into the table.
        while (rs.next()) {
            if (rs.getString("name").equals(userName) 
                && rs.getString("password").equals(password)) {
                errorMsg = "null";

                // Start a session with the client.
                FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                HttpSession session = (HttpSession)    fc.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
                System.out.println("Session ID = " + session.getId());
                // Return the "welcome.xhtml" page.
                return "welcome";
            }
        }
    } catch(SQLException sqlEx) {
        System.out.println("Error code: " + sqlEx.getErrorCode());
    }
    errorMsg = "Invalid user. Please try again";
    return null;
}

}
```

I think there's no need to post my `web.xml`, since it's pretty obvious for such an application.

Could someone help me to implement such a logout process correctly?

Comment: "Does nothing" is an end-user description. Check network traffic.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value And off-topic: Use a good tutorial. Doing plain jdbc in a managed bean is not good practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao

Comment: @Kukeltje I just checked the HTTPs traffic. Haven't seen any request related to the logout button. I really don't know why my `<h:commandButton>` doesn't respond at all.

Comment: @Kukeltje As for the design of the managed bean, I'm a novice in JSF, so I opted to focus on the app logic. I didin't followed any tutorial when coded this app. Any suggestion for a good JSF tutorial would be welcome.