# Disable button not calling java method correctly?

Tags: java, sql, jsf, stored-procedures, facescontext

I am having some trouble calling my java method. So, I have button in my front end in jsf. Where, I am calling my java method to disable 2 factor, I have sql procedure as well. Can any one check my java method and my sql statement, if all is well. Thanks

Here is my code:
(java method)

```
public void disableTwoFactor() throws SQLException {
    CallableStatement ps = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet result = null;
    getConfirmationCode();

    if (confirmationCodeFromUser.equals(Integer.toString(confirmationCodeFromServer))) {

        try {

            //get database connection
            conn = DataUtility.getDataSource().getConnection();

            ps = conn.prepareCall(strDisableTwoFactor);  

            ps.clearParameters();

            ps.setInt(1, this.id);
            ps.setString(2, this.number);
            ps.setString(3, this.passwordConfirmationStatus);
            ps.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            ps.executeQuery();

            getPassStatus(conn);
            result = (ResultSet) ps.getObject(4);
            result.next();
            if (result.getString(1).equals("YES")) {
                if (displayPassSignupPage == true) {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("codeVerify",
                            new FacesMessage("You  are now two-factor free"));
                } else {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("codeVerify",
                            new FacesMessage("You  are now two-factor free"));
                }

            } 

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            ps = null;
            conn = null;
        }

    }  
}
```

> SQL Statement

```
private static final String strDisableTwoFactor = "{call BEAN.DD_DISABLE_TWO_FACTOR(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
```

Comment: Narrow down the problem. 99.999% of the JSF questions is NOT sql related (not evgen JPA). and 99.99999% of the SQL questions is not JSF related. If the method is not called it is not SQL related. Remove all that code from your Q and make it a [mcve]. And there is NOTHING JSF related in your question so it is effectively a rather bad investigated and formulated one. Oh and if it is a jsf related method, it is bad practice to have it throw an  SQLEXception... Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Answer (score 0):

I think in your java code you want to update the database record via `procedure`

So change `ps.executeQuery()` to `ps.executeUpdate()`

Because `ps.executeQuery()` is just used for query!

Comment: that's good but my method is not firing still. Is everything seems fine?

Comment: you mean your method is not invoked?Then you need to debug your code to find why,especially `if (confirmationCodeFromUser.equals(Integer.toString(confirmationCodeFromServer)))`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. And weird... Who upvoted this answer?

Comment: @Kukeltje I do not know who upvote it,but why you down vote it? I have point out a bug for it,I think that's the reason why someone upvote it

Comment: Because your answer is not related to the question. The method is not even called so the cause is before all the sql stuff. OP tagged and formulated the question totally wrong. You might be right that it is wrong but that is more an additional comment than the reason for the actual problem