# Java Server Faces Managed Bean

Tags: jsf

I am somehow beginner in JavaServer Faces. I created Person class with setter and getters accordingly index.xhtml file. I`m taking values from database and showing in index.xhtml page. But In new second.xhtml file I cannot take those values from Person Managed bean java class. What is the problem? I searched configuration of Managed beans but could not find an answer.  My source code is here:

```
index.xhtml
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
        <h:head>
            <title>Facelet Title</title>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <!--Row Element is Selected-->
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          //get row contents

          $("#userTbl tbody tr").click(function(){

            var tableData=$(this).children("td").map(function(){
              return $(this).text();
            }).get();
                                    var td=tableData[0]+'*'+tableData[1]+'*'+tableData[2]+'*'+tableData[3];
    //                               alert(td);
                                   var tr1=tableData[0];
                                   var tr2=tableData[1];
                                   var tr3=tableData[2];
                                   var tr4=tableData[3];
    //                               document.getElementById('editForm:tx1').innerHTML = tr;
                                   document.getElementById('editForm:tx1').value = tr1;
                                   document.getElementById('editForm:tx2').value = tr2;
                                   document.getElementById('editForm:tx3').value = tr3;
                                   document.getElementById('editForm:tx4').value = tr4;


          });

        });

          });

      </script>
                   <!--ROw Elements are selected is finished--> 

    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mainStyle.css"/>
              <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="popup.css"/>
              <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="anim.css"/>
               <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="profile.css"/>

        </h:head>
        <h:body>
      <div class="upper" style="margin-left: 200px;">
            <h:form id="editForm">

                <h:inputText styleClass="inpp" id="tx1" value="#{Person.id}" style="display: none;"/>
                <h:inputText styleClass="inpp" id="tx2" value="#{Person.fname}"  style="display: none;"/>             
                <h:inputText styleClass="inpp" id="tx3" value="#{Person.lname}"  style="display: none;"/>
                <h:inputText styleClass="inpp" id="tx4" value="#{Person.dept}"  style="display: none;"/>
                <h:commandButton id="butr" onclick="popp();" value="delete" action="#{Person.dellete()}" style="display: none;"/>
            </h:form>
           </div>

            <form>
                <div class="container" >
                    <h2 style="margin-left: 500px;">Admin Paneli</h2>
             <div class="updat">
                 <button type="button" id="upd" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Qo`shish</button>
             </div>      
                    <div class="form-group pull-right" style="margin-right: 100px;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="What you lookin for?"></input>
                    </div>

                <table class="table table-striped" id="userTbl">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
                                    <th>Department</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                       <ui:repeat var="o" value="#{main.list}" varStatus="status">
          <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{o.id}" /></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{o.fname}" /></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{o.lname}"/></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{o.dept}" /></td>
          </tr>

           </ui:repeat>
        </tbody>

                </table>

                </div>
            </form>


        </h:body>
    </html>


My Person.java

package net.best;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="Person")
@RequestScoped
public class Person {

    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String dept;

    private String sid;

    public String getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(String sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    public Person(){

    }


    public String dellete(){     
               try {
        Connection connection =null; 
        DBConnect obj_DB_connect = new DBConnect();
        connection=obj_DB_connect.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("delete from person where lname='"+lname+"'");
            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


      return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

   public String update(){
           try {
        Connection connection =null; 
        DBConnect obj_DB_connect = new DBConnect();
        connection=obj_DB_connect.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("update person set id='"+id+"',fname='"+fname+"',lname='"+lname+"',dept='"+dept+"' where id='"+id+"'");
            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }


      return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
   }


    //Adding New Users
    public void add_Person(){

        try {

        Connection connection =null; 
        DBConnect obj_DB_connect = new DBConnect();
        connection=obj_DB_connect.getConnection();


           PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("insert into person(id,fname,lname,dept) value('"+id+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+dept+"')");
           ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }


} 
MainController.java
package net.best;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "main")
@SessionScoped 
public class MainController {

    ListQuery query =new ListQuery();

    private List<Person> list=new ArrayList<Person>();

    public List<Person> getList(){
        list=query.listPerson();
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Person> list){
        this.list=list;
    }
}
>Second.xhtml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<!--Row Element is Selected-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      //get row contents

      $("#userTbl tbody tr").click(function(){

        var tableData=$(this).children("td").map(function(){
          return $(this).text();
        }).get();
                                var td=tableData[0]+'*'+tableData[1]+'*'+tableData[2]+'*'+tableData[3];

                               var tr1=tableData[0];
                               var tr2=tableData[1];
                               var tr3=tableData[2];
                               var tr4=tableData[3];


      });

    });


  </script>

        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mainStyle.css"/>
          <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="popup.css"/>
          <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="anim.css"/>
           <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="profile.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <!--//USer table-->
        <form>
            <div class="container">
                <h2 style="margin-left: 500px;">Admin Paneli</h2>
    <div class="form-group pull-right" style="margin-right: 100px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="What you lookin for?"></input>
                </div>

            <table class="table table-striped" id="userTbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Department</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                   <ui:repeat var="obj" value="#{main.list}" varStatus="status">
      <tr>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{obj.id}" /></td>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{obj.fname}" /></td>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{obj.lname}"/></td>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{obj.dept}" /></td>
      </tr>

       </ui:repeat>
    </tbody>

            </table>

            <h1>sdfsf</h1>
            <h:outputText value="Hello"></h:outputText>
            <h:outputText value="#{Person.dept}"></h:outputText>


            </div>
        </form>
        <!--//User table is finished-->


    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question ans split the one code block in multiple ones per xhtml, class etc... And please use a newer tutorial (assuming you use jsf 2.2 or up). Don't use `@ManagedBeans` but `@Named` (CDI ones), don't do sql in beans but in services (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao) And read about [mcve] and try to create one. Also see http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. Cheers

Comment: oh and shouldn't the `<form>` be an `<h:form>`