# JSF Client error consuming Rest Service made with JAX-RS

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-8

I try to test the methods established in the restservice (JAX-RS) with a separate client made in jsf, the test is simply to press a button and execute the method.

JAX-RS service code

```
@Stateless
@Path("/personas")
public class PersonaServiceRS {

    @Inject
    private IPersonaService personaService;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<Persona> listarPersona(){
        System.out.println("Listar personas");
        return personaService.listarPersonas();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("{id}")
    public Persona buscarPersonaPorID(@PathParam("id") int id){
        System.out.println("buscarporId: " + id);
        return personaService.buscarPersonaPorId(new Persona(id));
    }

    @POST
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response agregarPersona(Persona persona) {
        try {
            personaService.registrarPersona(persona);
            System.out.println("Persona agregada: " + persona);
            return Response.ok().entity(persona).build();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @PUT
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response modificarPersona(@PathParam("id") int id, Persona personaForm){
        try {
            Persona persona = personaService.buscarPersonaPorId(new Persona(id));
            if(persona != null){
                personaService.modificarPersona(personaForm);
                System.out.println("Persona modificada: " + personaForm);
                return Response.ok().entity(personaForm).build();
            }else{
                return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response eliminarPersona(@PathParam("id") int id){
        System.out.println("Entre Eliminar");
        try{
            personaService.eliminarPersona(new Persona(id));
            System.out.println("Persona Eliminada con id: " + id);
            return Response.ok().build();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            return Response.status(404).build();
        }
    }

}
```

client index.xhml in jsf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Prueba JSF Form!</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputLabel value="Prueba de JSF!" />

        <h1>Opciones de Aplicativo</h1>


        <br/><br/><br/>
        <h:form>

            <h:commandButton value="Encontrar persona por ID" action="#{personaController.encontrarPersonaId()}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

controller class PersonaController jsf

```
package co.com.prueba.controllers;

import co.com.prueba.services.PersonaRestService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.*;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PersonaController implements Serializable{

    public void encontrarPersonaId(){
        System.out.println("encontrarPersonaID");
        PersonaRestService personaService = new PersonaRestService();
        String nombrePersona = personaService.encontrarPersonaId(1);
        System.out.println("nombrePersona 1: " + nombrePersona);
    }


}
```

service class PersonaRestService

```
import co.com.prueba.model.Persona;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class PersonaRestService {

    private static final String URL_BASE = "http://localhost:8585/ProyectoPrueba/webservice";

    private static Client cliente;
    private static WebTarget webTarget;
    private static Persona persona;
    private static List<Persona> personas;
    private static Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder;
    private static Response response;

    public String encontrarPersonaId(int id){
        System.out.println("Entre encontrar persona con id: " + id);
        cliente = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        webTarget = cliente.target(URL_BASE).path("/personas");

        System.out.println("Creo el webTarget:" + webTarget);

        persona = webTarget.path("/1").request().get(Persona.class);  //path y despues request
        System.out.println("Persona recuperada por id: " + persona);

        return persona.getNombre();
    }
}
```

client pom.xml in jsf

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>co.com.prueba</groupId>
    <artifactId>ClienteRsProyectoPrueba</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ClienteRsProyectoPrueba</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.30.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

==== Testing the findPersonaId method from this main class, It works fine:

```
public class TestConsolaClases {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PersonaRestService rs = new PersonaRestService();
        String nombre  = rs.encontrarPersonaId(1);
        System.out.println("nombre: " + nombre);
    }
}
```

However, from the jsf index, when executing, it generates the following error:

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;

root cause

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;

```
Initializing Soteria 1.0 for context '/ClienteRsProyectoPrueba'|#]
  Inicializando Mojarra 2.3.2 ( 20170627-2139 e63598abf2ed2bb1a24674f308a734e0dce18a72) para el contexto '/ClienteRsProyectoPrueba'|#]
  Loading application [ClienteRsProyectoPrueba] at [/ClienteRsProyectoPrueba]|#]
  ClienteRsProyectoPrueba was successfully deployed in 3.120 milliseconds.|#]
  encontrarPersonaID|#]
  Entre encontrar persona con id: 1|#]
  Creo el webTarget:JerseyWebTarget { http://localhost:8585/ProyectoPrueba/webservice/personas }|#]
  #{personaController.encontrarPersonaId()}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;
javax.faces.FacesException: #{personaController.encontrarPersonaId()}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:119)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:330)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.getProperties(SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationProvider.getProperties(SystemPropertiesConfigurationProvider.java:29)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.readExternalPropertiesMap(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.configure(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFeature.configure(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFeature.java:26)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:635)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureMetaProviders(ClientConfig.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:324)
    at co.com.prueba.services.PersonaRestService.encontrarPersonaId(PersonaRestService.java:31)
    at co.com.prueba.controllers.PersonaController.encontrarPersonaId(PersonaController.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:304)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:535)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
|#]
StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.getProperties(SystemPropertiesConfigurationModel.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.SystemPropertiesConfigurationProvider.getProperties(SystemPropertiesConfigurationProvider.java:29)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.readExternalPropertiesMap(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.configure(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.config.ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFeature.configure(ExternalPropertiesConfigurationFeature.java:26)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:635)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureMetaProviders(ClientConfig.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:456)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:826)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:428)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:324)
    at co.com.prueba.services.PersonaRestService.encontrarPersonaId(PersonaRestService.java:31)
    at co.com.prueba.controllers.PersonaController.encontrarPersonaId(PersonaController.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:304)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:535)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:107)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:330)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:870)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1418)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'jsf client' And even in this context I think you mean a jax-rs client that is used from a JSF 'controller' The latter is a bad design, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao. And the error is clear... And the error is happens in **your** class...

Comment: Oh and effectively the client NEVER knows in which technology the rest server side is made in (nor should it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply

But I don't understand what the error is.

I have two different projects
1. The first one has the logic of the rest service (business layer and data layer)
2. The second one has the presentation layer with a jax-rs client

In the "controller" the error does not occur,
Error occurs in the PersonaRestService class

Comment: the error is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.LocalizationMessages.WARNING_PROPERTIES()Ljava/lang/String;`

Comment: correct so ask if anyone knows how to solve it :)

Comment: Hello if you were able to solve to problem can you let us know how did you do it?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Jersey when you use the version that supports localized log messages. Which application server do you use?